# QueryDSL array overlap subquery function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jpa, querydsl

Having a table with a **jsonb** column that contains, amongst others, an **array** of **objects**, I've managed to devise a query that finds the rows with any elements that match at least one argument:

```sql
SELECT uuid, data FROM product p
WHERE arrayoverlap(array(SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'codes')->>'value'), array['57060279', '57627120']);
```

The data looks something like this:

```
{"name": "Peppermint", "codes": [{"type": "EAN-8", "value": "57627120"}, {"type": "EAN-8", "value": "57060279"}], "number": "000000000000002136"]}
{"name": "AnotherNameForPeppermint", "codes": [{"type": "EAN-8", "value": "57060279"}], "number": "000000000000009571"}
```

Is there a way to run these using QueryDSL?
I've managed to run some basic functions so far, that allow me to match single values, but for arrays I can't find out how.

```java
import com.querydsl.core.types.Expression;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.BooleanExpression;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.ComparablePath;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.EntityPathBase;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.StringExpression;

import static com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions.booleanTemplate;
import static com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions.stringTemplate;

public class QuerydslUtil {
    public static BooleanExpression jsonbContains(StringExpression haystack, Expression<String> needle) {
        return booleanTemplate("FUNCTION('jsonb_contains', {0}, {1}) = true", haystack, needle);
    }

    public static StringExpression jsonbExtractPath(Object data, String propertyName) {
        return getStringExpression("jsonb_extract_path", data, propertyName);
    }

    public static StringExpression jsonbExtractPathText(Object data, String propertyName) {
        return getStringExpression("jsonb_extract_path_text", data, propertyName);
    }

    public static StringExpression getStringExpression(String function, Object data, String propertyName) {
        return stringTemplate("FUNCTION('" + function + "', {0}, {1})", data, propertyName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way:
New helper methods:

```java
public class QuerydslUtil {
    public static BooleanExpression jsonbExistsAny(StringExpression arrayProperty, StringExpression array) {
        return booleanTemplate("FUNCTION('jsonb_exists_any', {0}, {1}) = true", arrayProperty, array);
    }

    public static BooleanExpression jsonbExistsAny(StringExpression arrayProperty, Collection<?> array) {
        String string = array.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(","));
        return jsonbExistsAny(arrayProperty, stringToArray(string));
    }

    public static StringExpression stringToArray(String string) {
        return stringTemplate("FUNCTION('string_to_array', {0}, {1})", constant(string), constant(","));
    }
}
```

And then:

```java
StringExpression codesPath = jsonbExtractPath($.data, "codes");
StringExpression codesValues = jsonbExtractPathText(codesPath, "value");
// executor is a Spring Data QuerydslPredicateExecutor
// codes is a Set<String>
Iterable<Product> products = executor.findAll(jsonbExistsAny(codesValues , codes));
```